# Excel Cut a Single cell into half?

Tags: excel, format

I know about merging cells, use text to column to split cell data & split the 
cell diagonally. The following image can illustrate the same effect of "cutting" cell into half. [Ignore the merged cells (A & B), treat them all as single cells, trying to illustrate the idea here.]

[image]

But I'm looking at ways that cut the cell into half like the image shown. Is it possible to do so?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Each cell in Excel has a definite address (e.g. "A1"). In your case you would have a cell D3(part1) and D3(part2) what is not possible.

If you vice versa merge two cells, every cell still has its definite address although you can't use the second cell any more. So in first image you don't really split a cell but you just use single (unmerged) cells.

Comment: Updated my example, seems a bit misleading. Thanks for the clarification.